# asp.net mvc use enum to display textvalue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am using asp.net mvc 4 and in my page I have a list of payments:

```
id | status| customerid
1  | 1     | 2
```

code:

```
  <tr>
            <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td>

         @{
            var status = ((status)(modelItem => item.StatusId)).toString();
         }

            </td>
            <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerId)
            </td>
         </tr>
```

I have defined an enum in my controller:

```
enum status { Pending = 1, Paid = 2 };
```

How can I display the text ie Pending instead of the id 1 on my razorpage? I am gettting an error now:

```
 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'MyApp.Models.status' because it is not a delegate type
```

Comment: Have a look here http://paulthecyclist.com/2013/05/24/enum-dropdown/

Answer (score 1):

You can extend HtmlHelper (a method that will render text instead of id number)
See [How to extend html helper](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast in enum first as

```
var status=((status)(modelItem => item.StatusId)).toString();
```

this should give you the name of the enum.

And then you can use `@Html.Label(` to render it on your view rather than `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusId)`

More details about [casting enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)